# How to delete an (@ManyToOne) Entity without cascade deleting ChildEntities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I got the following Entity in a Spring, JPA Setup:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    //Id
    //some object variables

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Person mother;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Person father;
}
```

I want to delete a Person, that is a mother/father of an other Person. On the contrary to other posts I found, I only want to delete that specific Person and all foreign key that are related to that Entity. So that the ChildEntities remain untouched (except for the foreign key of the Parent) in the DB. Am I missing a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? If you delete a person, the foreign key columns for other objects referring to that Person through a *ToOne association will be set to null. If you have a not null constraint on the database, you will get a null constraint violation by the database.

Comment: If I try to delete a person, that's a mother/fahter of an other person I'm getting a IntegrityConstraintViolationException. The foreign key columns are nullable, so that should be no problem.

Comment: Maybe some other foreign key is violated then. Without further details it's hard to analyze this.